# Finding unknown variance in order to maximize probability given a Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian

Given a Gaussian (Normal) Random Variable that has a known mean, μ, and unknown variance $\sigma^2,$ how would we determine the variance in order to maximize the probability, $P[X_1<X<X_2]?$

The way I think about this is in order to maximize the probability, I set the derivative with respect to sigma of, $${\int\displaystyle {\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {x-\mu }{\sigma  }}\right)^{2}}}$$ equal to 0. However, I don't know where to go after that.

Comment: Note that this is only interesting when $\mu \lt x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 < x_2 < \mu$.  Otherwise make the variance as close to $0$ as possible

Answer (score 2):

Letting $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and noting that $Z$ and $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ are equal in distribution, then

\begin{align*}
P(x_1 \le X \le X_2) 
&= P \left (\frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} 
 \le \frac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
&= P \left (\frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma} \le Z 
 \le \frac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
&= \Phi \left ( \frac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi \left ( \frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
\end{align*}

where $\Phi$ denotes the cdf of the standard normal, i.e. $\Phi(z) = P(Z \le z)$. Now, differentiate this expression with respect to $\sigma$ and set equal to zero yields:

$$
0 = -\frac{(x_2-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \phi \left ( \frac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma}\right) 
+\frac{(x_1-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \phi \left ( \frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$
where $\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-z^2/2}$ denotes the pdf of the standard normal, and $\frac{d}{dz} \Phi(z) = \phi(z)$. Rearranging the above yields
\begin{align*}
&(x_2-\mu) \phi \left ( \frac{x_2-\mu}{\sigma}\right) 
=(x_1-\mu) \phi \left ( \frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
\implies &
(x_2-\mu) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left \{ -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (x_2-\mu)^2 \right \}
=(x_1-\mu)  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left \{ -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (x_1-\mu)^2 \right \}\\
\implies &
\frac{x_2-\mu}{x_1 - \mu}  
=   \frac{\exp \left \{ -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (x_1-\mu)^2 \right \}}{ 
\exp \left \{ -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (x_2-\mu)^2 \right \}
}\\
\implies &
\frac{x_2-\mu}{x_1 - \mu}  
=   \exp \left \{ -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}[ (x_1-\mu)^2 - (x_2-\mu)^2] \right \}\\
\implies &
\log \left ( \frac{x_2-\mu}{x_1 - \mu}  \right)
=   -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}[ (x_1-\mu)^2 - (x_2-\mu)^2]\\
\implies & \sigma^2 = \frac{- [ (x_1-\mu)^2 - (x_2-\mu)^2]}{ \log \left ( \frac{x_2-\mu}{x_1 - \mu}  \right)}
\end{align*}

and as noted in the comment, we must have $\frac{x_2-\mu}{x_1-\mu}>0$ for the final expression to be defined

Comment: +1: note that you need $\frac{x_2-\mu}{x_1 - \mu}>0$ for this to make sense

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my solution